Apache Machine-readable status metrics does not return all the metadata
OS: Centos 7
Apache: 2.4.6
Below is what I see as an output of the curl command.
curl http://localhost/server-status?auto
Total Accesses: 499
Total kBytes: 446
CPULoad: .152377
Uptime: 6438
ReqPerSec: .0775085
BytesPerSec: 70.9388
BytesPerReq: 915.238
BusyWorkers: 1
IdleWorkers: 99
ConnsTotal: 1
ConnsAsyncWriting: 0
ConnsAsyncKeepAlive: 1
ConnsAsyncClosing: 0
Scoreboard: ____________________________________________________W_______________________________________________................................................................................................

Looking at the output, one can see that it doesn't have ServerVersion, ServerMPM, Load1, and many more metadata.

Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.
Both Centos and Apache versions are out of support

The information you show appears in line with what the manual says you should see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html   ; why do you think you’re not getting everything you ought to?

@HBruijn, I have reviewed the manual, and all settings mentioned are in place. Expecting similar output as below:
root@ ~]# curl localhost/server-status?auto
localhost
ServerVersion: Apache/2.4.37 (CentOS Stream) OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_jk/1.2.46
ServerMPM: event
Server Built: Feb 16 2024 08:57:19
CurrentTime: Tuesday, 16-Jul-2024 14:48:14 UTC
RestartTime: Monday, 15-Jul-2024 14:28:14 UTC
ParentServerConfigGeneration: 1
ParentServerMPMGeneration: 0
ServerUptimeSeconds: 87599
ServerUptime: 1 day 19 minutes 59 seconds
Load1: 0.02
Load5: 0.06
Load15: 0.08

@RomeoNinov Yes, Centos is out of support, but Apache 2.4.6 is not. The observation I mentioned is related to Apache. Let me know if you believe that it's Centos causing the behavior.

Mod_status may not have extended status set to on and possibly other directives like ServerTokens may change what gets displayed as well

@HBruijn Below is set in the httpd.conf
<Location "/server-status">
SetHandler server-status
Require all granted
Order allow,deny
allow from all

ExtendedStatus On
How do you check whether ExtendedStatus is On or not?

I got the solution. The Apache 2.4.6 mod_status module does not provide much machine-readable status. Upgrading to version 2.4.37 solved the requirement.
I didn't find the option to mark it as resolved or close the thread. Maybe I am new and trying to be well versed with this platform.
Thank you everyone who has contributed to this post.
